# Can't find System.Windows.Forms.Textbox Background property

Tags: c#, background, textbox

I tried to add watermark in my `TextBox`. So I find a [sample in msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613590%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#feedback). But when I tried to use this Visual Studio can't find the `TextBox.Background` property. How to solve it?

Comment: Is this a WinForms application or WPF?

Comment: @Savanna It is WinForms. I've also included `PresentationFramework` and `PresentationCore` references.

Comment: That's why. The code you are referencing uses System.Windows.Controls, not System.Windows.Forms. The WinForms textbox doesn't have a Background property.

Comment: Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: Looks like you can host WPF controls in WinForms (see http://tech.pro/tutorial/799/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms) I've never personally done and I think it would be better to just do the whole project WPF if you can or create a custom control.